# AJAX Silent Update from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to update a paragraph from my html document using ajax but its not working and there is not error. 
It simply does not change the value of the paragraph. 
Is there an error in my code?
Thank you.

PHP/XML:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type :text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes"?>';
    echo '<response>';

    $connect = mysql_connect("****","***","****"); 
    mysql_select_db("****");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE number=1");
    $query2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    echo $query2['q1'];
    echo '</response>';
?>
```

javascript

```
<script>
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequstObject();
function createXmlHttpRequstObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        xmlHttp=false;
    }

    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("NOPE");
    else 
        return xmlHttp;
}
    function refresh() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0){
            xmlHttp.open("GET","ref.php",true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        } else {
            setTimeout('refresh()',1000);
        }
    }
    function handleServerResponse(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var message= xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML=message;
            setTimeout('refresh()', 1000);
        }
    }
 </script>
```

HTML:

Comment: can you post some sample output?

Comment: The output data that I echo is correct, but when I try to capture it in javascript it returns nothing

Comment: I meant post it so we can test with it...

Comment: I would use an ajax library like jQuery.

Comment: you're generating xml output and dumping in arbitrary text into that xml. If any of the data form the DB contains xml metacharacters (especially tags like html), you're going to be generating bad/broken xml and screwing up the JS code.